# How should a CD RW be formatted to install an OS

Tags: boot, operating-systems, iso-image, media-creation-tool

I have the windows 10 media creation tool as an ISO on my desktop. I insert a CD RW into my pc, and I am prompted to format it for first time use. I have 2 options to format.[image]

The "Which should I choose" section is not enough. I am installing an OS to boot my pc from an external source.

I have each option before for different purposes, but now I want my device to be able to read the CD when I hit F12 to open the boot setup

Comment: Iirc, you want to *install* W10 on a CDRW? In my opinion a bad idea. Just the install procedure writes and modifies so many files that your disk will soon be worn out. Better install on hard disk or SSD, then customize the OS to your needs and for Start from read-only disk. And as a last step burn it to CD (actually I think you'll need a DVD, or even BD).

Comment: @TobiasKnauss - Yeah well that's a school task so I have to.

Comment: Never heard of something like that being a school task. If you do it right, I think it'll take hours...

Comment: @TobiasKnauss, he obviously does not talk about "installing" it to be used from the disk but to create an installation media to install it on hard drives.

Comment: @Yisroel Tech: but then he should have chosen a different title on his question.

Comment: I think it's more suitable as a comment. That's correct what Yisroel states. A CD will now hold an OS, it's way too big. A CD is maxed at 700MB? You need minimum a DVD if not a Blue Ray DVD or a Dual or Double DVD. But if you must, you can use the second radio button, "burn in groups", it will have to be a multiple CD installation. So if your software can do it, it will require a CD1, CD2... CDn.

Comment: @ejbytes: [What?](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Huh? Where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just **Cancel** this popup and let the ISO burning format the CD.

But, honestly, a Windows installation does not fit onto a CD-RW, you'll need a DVD disk.

Comment: It doesn't work. I have to choose an option to continue or else nothing happens

Comment: Anyway, You are right. I can't do that the CD is too small.

Comment: what do you mean by "nothing happens"? What method were you using to try burning the CD?

Comment: First of all right clickinng the ISO there is no "burn"option. So I attempt to just open the cd first. But I can't open it unless I choose.

Comment: You will not have anything from opening the CD. Interesting that you don't have the burn to disk option. Did you right-click the ISO file?

Comment: Yes. I did that.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what options it gave you?

Comment: I already did. I think it's clear enough

Comment: You posted a screenshot of the pop up when you put it in the CD. I was asking for a screenshot of the right click menu for the ISO file.